# Loop through a matrix and assign different values

Tags: r

I have this loop:

```
for (j in 1:n){
```

And i have a few lines of code, and i have another matrix, which holds a few rows like:

```
shape  scale
1      2
34     45
12     12
```

And i use this parameters:

```
shape[j] scale[j]
```

Now, when i loop i have a lot of other variables so i need that loop, but i would like to loop for the shape and scale parameter in a different way, so, if j=2 i don't necessarily want the shape and scale to come from the 2nd row, but i want them to take values from a random row but without repetition.

Someone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be searching the function [`sample`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sample.html) and in particular its option `replace=FALSE`.

I think you should create an array in this way:

```
indices <- sample(n, 1:nrow(X), replace = FALSE)
```

where `X` is the matrix where you have the shapes and scales.

Then in your loop, the index you use to access to your matrix with shapes and scales is `indices[j]`.